# Swift property observing doesn't override

Tags: ios, swift, properties, overriding

I wrote class inheritance with property override. I found stored property observing doesn't work like other overriding.

These classes have stored property and calculated property for compare.

```
class Parent {
    var storedProp : Int! {
        didSet {
            print("Parent stored property didSet")
        }
    }
    var calcProp : Int {
        print("Parent calculated property get")
        return 100
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    override var storedProp : Int! {
        didSet {
            print("Child stored property didSet")
        }
    }

    override var calcProp : Int {
        print("Child calculated property get")
        return 101
    }
}
```

When I instantiate Child object and get calculated property. Property in child class override and doesn't work parent's.

```
var obj = Child()
let value = obj.calcProp
```

I expected same thing happen on property observing, but property observing of child and parent both works. It looks like propagated.

```
obj.storedProp = 999

// Parent stored property didSet
// Child stored property didSet
```

Is it intended?.. and How can i prevent the propagation?

Comment: You've made some observations but what is your question?

Comment: I forget to write the question. I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) section of The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2) describes 'overriding property observers' as 'adding property observers'

> Overriding Property Observers
>
> You can use property overriding to add property observers to an
>   inherited property...

If a subclass were able to override `didSet` observer of `currentSpeed` property of `AutomaticCar` class in the following example:

```
class AutomaticCar {
    var currentSpeed: Double {
        didSet {
            gear = Int(currentSpeed / 10.0) + 1
        }
    }
}
```

The `didSet` in the subclass would prevent updating `gear` property which could break the designed behavior of the super class, AutomaticCar.

Comment: It's appending new observers to the property, not replacing. So it would not prevent updating the `gear` property. Also the didSet you add in you child class are called after the parent class didSet.

Comment: @LudovicLandry You are right and I meant overriding is not possible and try to pick an example of a problem when it is possible. Maybe it’s my English writing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s value.  There are two observers `willSet` and `didSet`.  *There are no observers for getting a property (i.e. no `willGet` and no `didGet`).*

In your `calcProp` property definitions, you have overridden the `get` *computed property* not the (non-existant) `didGet` property observer.  Your call to get a value from the child, calls only the `get` method on the child's property.  Neither the child nor the parent is observing the get.

To prevent the effect you are seeing: when setting a property you should be implementing the `set` computed property.  You must remove the `didSet` observer from parent if you don't wan't it to observe changes in that value *even when the change is originating in a child*.